# TypeError: must be real number, not Circle

Tags: python, class, object, typeerror

```
import math as m
class Circle:
        def __init__(self,radius):
            self.radius = radius
            count = 0
        def area(r):
            k = m.pi * m.pow(r,2)
            return k
```

I am not sure what wrong with the code above but when I am trying execute like below

```
a = Circle(4)
a.area()
it throws an error like 
"   k = m.pi * m.pow(r,2)
TypeError: must be real number, not Circle"
```

Unable to understand how it's considering the float value as an instance to the circle.

Comment: Why `import math as m`?

Comment: Just for convenience to use m. instead of math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of an instance method is a reference to the instance itself (usually called `self`) - that's where the Circe is coming from. You shouldn't be passing the radius, you should be using the member you have:

```
def area(self):
    k = m.pi * m.pow(self.radius, 2)
    return k
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import math as m
DEFAULT_RADIUS = 0.5
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius=DEFAULT_RADIUS):
        self.radius = radius
        count = 0
    def area(self, r=None):
        if r is not None:
            self.radius = r
        k = m.pi * m.pow(self.radius, 2)
        return k
a = Circle(4)
a.area()
```